# Hide link from quick launch

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Our current Quick launch has a link to current page. i used the setting as below

[image]

In the parent site i had created a lot of links in the Quick launch which gets inherited by selecting the above option.

The problem is while going to any page it by default create the current page link to the quick launch like below.
[image]

how do i get rid of the default link?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to only display subsite specific links on your subsites, you need to have the 4th option selected **"Structural Navigation:  Display only the navigation items bellows the current site."**

[image]

Comment: no i need other sites too